# Weird/unreadable returned json encoding read by QByteArray to post request

Tags: json, qt, post, encoding, qbytearray

I try to scrap a website by requesting it api with a post request. The returned data in json has however a unreadble encoding, like this :

à^!ÚÄÆ›>Ã    ñ‹yÖž¥³ ¤hóúôë¼zC

The Content-Type of the request is "application/json; charset=utf-8". Someone has a idea about this weird encoding ? A priori the request works, else there is an explicit error. The same request with the navigator has a perfectly readable response. I'm using Qt, with QNetworkRequest. The answer goes in a QByteArray I read with toStdString(). If I try to reformat the QByteArray in QJsonDocument or QJsonObject before to read it, there is nothing in the answer.
Thank you by advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#fromJson) class, and use the static function to construct a JsonDocument by using a bytearray with UTF-8 format.

```
const QByteArray dataFromServer;
QJsonParseError er;
const QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json, &er);
if (er.error != QJsonParseError::NoError) {
   return false;
}
```

Then, take the [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html), and check if it's a list. You can iterate over the list or acces to a given value by using the key:

```
const QJsonObject object = doc.object();
const QString value = object.value(QLatin1String("My_key");
const std::string stdValue = value.toStdString();
```